# 7z command line doesn't split my compressed files

Tags: 7-zip

I'm trying to achieve the following via `7z` command line to compress a few folders' worth of files that add up to around 70Gb:

[image]

Notice the setting `Split to volumes, bytes` is set to `650M - CD`. If I run from the GUI like this it works perfectly and creates many 650Mb files. But when I run the following via Windows 10 cmd-line:

```
7z a -t7z F:\myzips\myzip.7z -mx9 -m0=lzma2:d=650m:fb=64 -ms=256m -mmt=8 F:\myfolder1 F:\myfolder2
```

...it seems to work, but it creates a single massive 11Gb .7z file instead of splitting it into 650Mb files as expected.

1. I thought `d=650m` should have achieved the splitting I was after.
2. Are any other settings in the cmd-line statement not matching the GUI? If so, how do I fix?

If you could give me a fully correct cmd-line for what I'm trying to do, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
7z a F:\myzips\myzip.7z -mx9 -v650m F:\myfolder1 F:\myfolder2
```